# Android, get previous state of activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, state

I need to get the state the activity just came out of, for example, I need to run some code in my onResume(), but only after it is called following onPause() and not on following on Start().

If onResume() is called after onStop() then I need to run some different code.

How should I properly check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.androidside.com/data/geditor/0812/1062731775_4e7c4d93_android+activity+life+cycle.jpg) is the lifecycle.  I think you can save a flag into your preferences and check it during onResume.  Here's some pseudo-code:

```
onStart() {
    saveFlagToPreferences(false);
}

onResume() {
    boolean doStuff = getFlagFromPrefs();
    if (doStuff) {
        //do some stuff following onPause
    } else {
        //do some stuff following onStop
    }
}

onPause() {
    saveFlagToPreferences(true);
}

onStop() {
    saveFlagToPreferences(false);
}
```

To load the preferences you can use something like:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppName",0);
settings.getBoolean("flag", true);
```

And to save them:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppName",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("flag",true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement this tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I didn't end up doing it this way, in fact i just used a global variable and had my onpause set the boolean, in which case it would be false on start and resume if onpause hadn't already been called. I don't know which is considered a better solution but mine works fine.